# Aqua Data studio not connected to remote Database using Db2

Tags: db2, database-connection, remote-server

I am using Db2 and Aqua data studio 14.0.1, when trying to register a server I am getting error and unable to connect to remote Server.

Getting these two messages when click 'Test Connection':

1- Your server is accepting socket connections on HostName
and then

2-

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: DatabaseName
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(ed.java:679)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(ed.java:60)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(ed.java:127)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.jb.a(jb.java:4485)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.q(ab.java:713)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.p(ab.java:586)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.l(ab.java:407)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.d(ab.java:145)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.Uc(b.java:1266)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.b(b.java:1184)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(b.java:5516)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.c(b.java:739)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.b(b.java:682)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(b.java:365)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.<init>(b.java:305)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(DB2SimpleDataSource.java:214)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:460)
at \\...\\ .\\हिñçêČάй語简�?한\\.eꋺꀈᠵ⧸ 4 int.a(Unknown Source)
at \\...\\ .\\हिñçêČάй語简�?한\\.tꄢꑪ⢎ꑅ default.Eu(Unknown Source)
at \\...\\ .\\हिñçêČάй語简�?한\\.tꄢꑪ⢎ꑅ default.ai(Unknown Source)
at \\...\\ .\\हिñçêČάй語简�?한\\.tꄢꑪ⢎ꑅ default.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at \\...\\ .\\हिñçêČάй語简�?한\\.tꄢꑪ⢎ꑅ default.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at \\...\\ .\\हिñçêČάй語简�?한\\.uꅭꌡꄒꂛ 2.ct(Unknown Source)
at \\...\\ .\\हिñçêČάй語简�?한\\.uꅭꌡꄒꂛ 2.c(Unknown Source)
at \\...\\ .\\हिñçêČάй語简�?한\\.Jᢔꋩ⢱ꅒ static double.d(Unknown Source)
at \\...\\ .\\हिñçêČάй語简�?한\\.Jᢔꋩ⢱ꅒ static double.b(Unknown Source)
at \\...\\ .\\हिñçêČάй語简�?한\\.Iꏏ⡚ꁮꑯ.Os(Unknown Source)
at \\...\\ .\\हिñçêČάй語简�?한\\.zꂚꁮꊗᛝ continue private.run(Unknown Source)
```

While If I use same properties and remote Db with some other version of Aqua data Studio, it works fine.

Is there any bug in this version of Aqua Studio?

Comment: looks like you have a standard connection issue. Are you sure that everything is setup correctly?

Comment: yes, 100% as I am using the same settings in Aqua 6.5.9 and it is working fine

Answer (score 1):

Aqua Studio contains db2 java driver that might does not work properly with your DB2. Please copy with replace db2java.jar or db2cc.jar files from your DB2 installation into Aqua Data Studio drivers folder and try to connect again.

Comment: Thank you for the response but this version doesn't have db2cc.jar, it has db2jcc.jar...Anyways I've changed dbServer for now  and it is working fine

Comment: Sorry for the typo. It's db2jcc.jar. I've already faced an issue like this and it works fine when it loads files from db2 installation.